# fill column based on value in rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe named emails_visits:

```
    Rep  Doctor       Date   type date_after
0     1       1 2021-01-25  email        NaT
1     1       1 2021-05-29  email        NaT
2     1       2 2021-03-15  email        NaT
3     1       2 2021-04-02  email        NaT
4     1       2 2021-04-29  email        NaT
30    1       2 2021-06-01  visit 2021-06-01
5     1       3 2021-01-01  email        NaT
6     1       3 2021-01-10  email        NaT
7     1       3 2021-01-25  email        NaT
8     1       3 2021-02-19  email        NaT
9     1       4 2021-03-03  email        NaT
```

I need to fill in column `date_after`from bottom to top based on values in column `Rep` and `Doctor`.
if values row(x-1) `Rep` and `Doctor` `==`values row(x) `Rep` and `Doctor`  `==` then `date_after`in row(x-1) should be == to`date_after`in row(x)

example of desired result below

```
    Rep  Doctor       Date   type date_after
0     1       1 2021-01-25  email        NaT
1     1       1 2021-05-29  email        NaT
2     1       2 2021-03-15  email 2021-06-01
3     1       2 2021-04-02  email 2021-06-01
4     1       2 2021-04-29  email 2021-06-01
30    1       2 2021-06-01  visit 2021-06-01
5     1       3 2021-01-01  email        NaT
6     1       3 2021-01-10  email        NaT
7     1       3 2021-01-25  email        NaT
8     1       3 2021-02-19  email        NaT
9     1       4 2021-03-03  email        NaT
```

Comment: Hi, what is it that you tried for this as code?

Comment: I tried df.apply with lambda and 2 ifs statements but got stuck how to iterate trough the rows

Comment: Update your question with the you have try so far. to avoid downvote :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`groupby_bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html):

```
df['date_after'] = df.groupby(['Rep', 'Doctor'])['date_after'].bfill()
print(df)

# Output
    Rep  Doctor        Date   type date_after
0     1       1  2021-01-25  email        NaT
1     1       1  2021-05-29  email        NaT
2     1       2  2021-03-15  email 2021-06-01
3     1       2  2021-04-02  email 2021-06-01
4     1       2  2021-04-29  email 2021-06-01
30    1       2  2021-06-01  visit 2021-06-01
5     1       3  2021-01-01  email        NaT
6     1       3  2021-01-10  email        NaT
7     1       3  2021-01-25  email        NaT
8     1       3  2021-02-19  email        NaT
9     1       4  2021-03-03  email        NaT
```